Azure AKS : how can i get OpenID Connect Issuer (oidc-issuer) and Workload identity from the PORTAL (not from Azure cli)?
I created an AKS cluster using the following azure cli command:
az aks create --resource-group "${RESOURCE_GROUP}" --name myAKSCluster --node-count 1 --enable-oidc-issuer --enable-workload-identity --generate-ssh-keys

Then i used :
az aks show --name benighil --resource-group "benighil_group" --query "oidcIssuerProfile.issuerUrl" -o tsv

to get : oidcIssuerProfile.issuerUrl
I would like to know how can i get oidcIssuerProfile.issuerUrl using the azure portal instead of using azure cli ?

Could you confirm whether your requirement is to find oidcIssuerProfile.issuerUrl value in Azure Portal?

Hello sir, yes : )

In Azure Portal, you can find it in Resource JSON of your Kubernetes Service. Check here https://i.imgur.com/ae2rmpV.png

When I below Azure CLI command, I got OpenID Connect Issuer URL as below:
az aks show --name aksname --resource-group "rgname" --query "oidcIssuerProfile.issuerUrl" -o tsv

Response:

To find this OpenID Connect Issuer URL value in Azure Portal, click on JSON View option of your Kubernetes service:

In this Resource JSON file, you can find value of OpenID Connect Issuer URL like this:


good job man, i accepted your answer and gave you +1 : )
